# Bellman Ford Algorithm in Java

Tags: java

Can Anyone help with bellman ford algorithm in java to calculate the shortest path from the source vertex.

I would also like the final updated predecessor nodes to be printed for each nodes after traversing all the edges and after all iterations
     This is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BellmanFord {
    LinkedList<Edge> edges;
    int d[];
    int n,e,s;
    final int INFINITY=999;

    private static class Edge  {
        int u,v,w;

        public Edge(int a, int b, int c)     {
            u=a;
            v=b;
            w=c;
        }
    }

    BellmanFord() throws IOException {
        int item;
        edges = new LinkedList<Edge>();
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter number of vertices ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());

        System.out.println("Cost Matrix");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)   {
                item = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
                if(item != 0)
                    edges.add(new Edge(i,j,item));
            }
        }

        e = edges.size();
        d = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Enter the source vertex ");
        s = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
    }

    void relax() {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
            d[i]=INFINITY;

        d[s] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < e; ++j) { //here i am calculating the shortest path
                if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v]) {
                    d[edges.get(j).v] = d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w;
                }
             }
         }
    }

    boolean cycle() {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < e; ++j)
            if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v])
                 return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException   {
        BellmanFord r = new BellmanFord();
        r.relax();
        if(r.cycle()) {
            for(int i=0;i<r.n;i++)
                System.out.println(r.s+" ==> "+r.d[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" There is a negative edge cycle ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the exactly problem your code is having? Can you give an example of sample input, sample output, actual output and what seems to be faulty?

Comment: Yes I can .. I am new to this Forum. So please acknowledge if i make some mistakes while posting

Comment: You are allowed to edit your question as much as you like to make it more readable/clarify what your problem is.

Comment: Enter number of vertices 3
Cost Matrix
0
1
2
0
0
3
-1
0
0
Enter the source vertex 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the standard [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), I think you should introduce an array for the     predecessors:

```
int[] p = new int[n];
```

Initialize in your `relax` function:

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
    d[i] = INFINITY;
    p[i] = -1;
}
```

And update together with the distance:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < e; ++j) { //here i am calculating the shortest path
        if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v]) {
            d[edges.get(j).v] = d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w;
            p[edges.get(j).v] = edges.get(j).u;
        }
    }
}
```

And print:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Vertex " + i " has predecessor " + p[i]);
}
```

**EDIT** Since you seem to have some problem with my code snippets, here the full working code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BellmanFord  {
    LinkedList<Edge> edges;
    int d[], p[];
    int n,e,s;
    final int INFINITY=999;

    private static class Edge  {
        int u,v,w;

        public Edge(int a, int b, int c)     {
            u=a;
            v=b;
            w=c;
        }
    }

    BellmanFord () throws IOException {
        int item;
        edges = new LinkedList<Edge>();
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter number of vertices ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());

        System.out.println("Cost Matrix");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)   {
                item = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
                if(item != 0)
                    edges.add(new Edge(i,j,item));
            }
        }

        e = edges.size();
        d = new int[n];
        p = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Enter the source vertex ");
        s = Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
    }

    void relax() {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
            d[i]=INFINITY;
            p[i] = -1;
        }

        d[s] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < e; ++j) { //here i am calculating the shortest path
                if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v]) {
                    d[edges.get(j).v] = d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w;
                    p[edges.get(j).v] = edges.get(j).u;
                }
             }
         }
    }

    boolean cycle() {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < e; ++j)
            if (d[edges.get(j).u] + edges.get(j).w < d[edges.get(j).v])
                 return false;
        return true;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Vertex " + i + " has predecessor " + p[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException   {
        BellmanFord  r = new BellmanFord ();
        r.relax();
        if(r.cycle()) {
            for(int i=0;i<r.n;i++)
                System.out.println(r.s+" ==> "+r.d[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" There is a negative edge cycle ");
        }

        r.print();
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Enter number of vertices 3
Cost Matrix
0
99
1
4
0
2
2
4
0
Enter the source vertex 0
```

Output:

```
0 ==> 0
0 ==> 5
0 ==> 1
Vertex 0 has predecessor -1
Vertex 1 has predecessor 2
Vertex 2 has predecessor 0
```

Which is as expected

Comment: @VenkyKoneri where? The only place I can image is at `p[edges.get(j).v]`, but then you'd also have an index out of bounds in your original code...

Comment: Should not i be written for each edges i.e for(j=0;j<e;j++) {

Comment: its showing the error is at p[i]=-1

Comment: @VenkyKoneri are you sure you initialized `int[] p = new int[n];`? It's working fine for me...

Comment: You have `n` vertices, so you set the predecessor of each of them to `-1`. Then, every time you update the weight of a path, you keep track of how you got there, by using `p[edges.get(j).v] = edges.get(j).u`. Both should be right.

Comment: yes i initialized. Still Giving the same error

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot Heuster.. :)